# Windows Server Backup 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-backup

I would like to do Full Server backup using the Windows Server Backup feature, but it always prompts **Volumes larger than 1777216 megabytes cannot be protected**. what does it means by cannot be protected?

Comment: Strange, the normal limit is 2088958, so your error is too early. In any case, if your backup is to a VHDX file this shouldn't happen up to 64TB. In general, I would advise using a third-party backup solution rather than Microsoft's fragile solution. For example [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).

Comment: My backup is to a VHDX file and the drive that I want to backup didn't exceed 1TB. This freeware is able to perform full backup?

Comment: Yes, it is extremely versatile and it also has a boot media for emergencies.

Comment: I couldn't install AOMEI Backupper Freeware on Windows Server... Anyone encountered the same issues as me, please share with me the info

Comment: Some products require the paid version for Windows Server. According to your needs try freeware products for [Drive Cloning](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-drive-cloning-software.htm) or [File-Based Backup](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-hard-drive-backup-program.htm).